# Where can I get a script that will rename all files in a folder to a string of random numbers?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch

I'd like it to have a configurable limit on the minimum and maximum amount of numbers the name can have. Ideally I'd like to have the name be a random sequence of 8 numbers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: `powershell ls ^|%{ren $_ -n $('{0:00000000}' -f (Random(100000000)))}` Use cryptographically strong random number generator:
`powershell 1..100^|%{New-Item ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()) -I f^|Out-Null}`